# Display field ONLY in edit mode using Page Layout

Tags: page-layout

Checkbox field.

I want to display checkbox ONLY in edit mode, using standard page layout.

Is there any way to achieve this without coding Visualforce page?

Comment: you want this in page layout?

Comment: @Ratan, yes. In standard page layout.

Comment: what i believe this is not possible. you may need visualforce page

Comment: @Ratan, this is my thought too. But I'm hoping someone have found simpler solution, then creating a whole VF page just for two fields, which should be hidden in specific mode.

Comment: Formula fields do not show up on the edit page, so the image part should be doable. As far as having edit only checkboxes you need to go for VF approach

Comment: @Rao, I understand VF possibility. And this is what I want to avoid - code VF page just for one checkbox field.

Comment: The only option that you  have is an inline edit vf page with just the edit only field. Render the field based on some custom setting/ profile setting

Comment: You could use a simple VF page with `apex:detail` and some simple jQuery to set the checkbox fields' CSS property to `display:none`. Requires a bit of Firebug or the like work to hack into the generated HTML and of course, the solution isn't supported by SFDC so it has fragility issues.  But I've done things like this before.

Comment: did u find any solution for this? i have the similar problem